# Is there a way to use ASMX services in Windows Universal Apps ?

Tags: wcf, asmx, win-universal-app

I was converting a program to Windows 10 and went to add the 'Service Reference' and then goto Advanced and then select ASMX but that option no longer exists.

Is there some easy way to get around this restriction  ?

Comment: You should be able to use Add Service Reference (WCF) to utilize a legacy ASMX service.

Comment: I did but for some reason the properties on certain class where not there. So I asked there support and they said WCF support is coming in the next version... I am not exactly sure why I see some things and not others ? This is the one I am using: http://titlehoundonline.com/titlehound_ws/v2/RateCalculatorService.asmx

Comment: The option for Universal app regarding Service Reference are not the same as say ASP.NET 4.0 'Service Reference'